# How do I set unique ringtones for individual contacts?

Tags: ringtone

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 and would like to set text notifications to be unique to each contact (just as I can set unique ringtones for each contact).  Is there a way to do this?  For example, I would like 1 ringtone/notification for my sister for both calls and text and a different ringtone/notification for my mother for both calls and text.

Answer (score 1):

There are many apps available for these tasks. But soon it becomes pain to have many apps running one for each purpose. At these situations, you can remove all those apps and use [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/).  You can set the Tasker such that when your mother calls or sends a text it can play a preset ringtone - and it can even say the caller name or any predefined text. This is just a tip of the iceberg and there are so many things that can be done with it.

It is a bit complicated for the first use and involves a small learning curve. But once you are used to it, you can eliminate many apps and make your phone a true smartphone.

Note: I am not in any way associated with Tasker other than using it in my device.